# Changing IBOutlet in UIViewController from UIWindow in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with some `IBOutlets`. I also have a `UIWindow` that needs to access those `IBOutlets` in the first `UIViewController`. However, whenever I try to access it from my `UIWindow`, the variables are `nil`. Here's some of my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playPauseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

    func functionA() {
        println(playPauseLabel)
        println(playButton)
        println(pauseButton)
    }
}

class WindowClass: UIWindow {

    func resetPlayPause() {

        var vc = ViewController()
        vc.functionA()

    }

}
```

Now when I call `func resetPlayPause()` from `WindowClass`, all three `IBOutlets` are nil. I've read around on the other SO threads on this issue but haven't found any solutions. How can I access and modify those `IBOutlets` in `ViewController` from `WindowClass`?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that `resetPlayPause()` is constructing a new instance of `ViewController` each time it's called, and unless your `ViewController` has an initializer that loads itself from a storyboard or xib, none of your outlets will be connected. If your `ViewController` *does* have an initializer that does this, it won't connect its outlets until its `view` has been loaded. You can do this simply by calling `vc.view` in `resetPlayPause()` before you toggle the buttons.

The harder answer is that having your window access a view controller's ivars directly seems like a really bad idea. Either move your `resetPlayPause()` method somewhere *other* than in a window subclass, or have it call a method on `ViewController` that will toggle the buttons internally.

Comment: See updated code. I've already tried what you mentioned: to call a method on `ViewController` that toggles its own buttons, but I only get `nil`. And the method does have to be in the window subclass. And by initialize, do you mean like this: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController`?

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of initializer that I meant.

Comment: Ok cool. Would you mind elaborating on exactly how to call vc.view?

Comment: Exactly like that: vc.view. The compiler may warn that the statement doesn't do anything.

Comment: My project won't build if I just call that. `Expression resolves to an unused I-value`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use NSNotificationCenter. Works like a charm.